# swift 4.1 ISO8601DateFormatter doesn't parse dates passed by MRAID ad content

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, iso8601

I don't have control over what date string is passed to me, and in the case of the MRAID 2.0 test ads (IAB) they use this odd date format:

```
2013-12-21T00:00-05:00
```

This does parse fine in some date formatters I've tested.. but not using ISO8601DateFormatter.

If I add the extra zeros:

2013-12-21T00:00:**00**-05:00,   then it works but again, I can't control what I'm sent.

Is there any way to configure it to read this date format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a regular `DateFormatter` with the needed `dateFormat` of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZZZZ` and be sure to set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

If you get date strings in multiple possible formats then try one format, if that returns `nil`, try the next possible format. Repeat for all the possible formats you have to handle.